Gaussian Integral and Solid of Revolution
I was thinking about a way to make the Gauss integral more explainable to Integral Calculus students and then came across with an idea:
After checking that $$\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\right)^2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$$
I thought that, since the volume below that surface is just the volume of a solid of revolution, if I could just calculate the radius I would be able to just calculate that volume as an application of the volume of revolution. And from here, it can be done: Just invert $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ to get an inverse function $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{-\ln x}$. Then the volume is just the improper integral:
$$\int_{0}^1 \pi (\sqrt{-\ln x})^2=-\pi\int_{0}^1 \ln x=\pi+\pi\lim_{a\to 0^+} (x\ln x -x)=\pi.$$
Therefore
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}=\sqrt{\int_{0}^1 \pi (\sqrt{-\ln x})^2}=\sqrt{\pi}.$$
My question would be: Is there any way to relate the integrals:
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}$ and $\int_{0}^1 \pi (\sqrt{-\ln x})^2,$ or in other words, the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}$ with a volume of the solid of revolution above, without appealing to the notion of double integrals as the volume under a surface?
Even without that, it's already some progress, since I only would need to reference that a double improper integral represents volume without needing to talk about changes of coordinates in double integrals and how they work. But if there were a different way of relating those integrals not using the notion of double integrals it would be more interesting.

In Calculus II/Integral Calculus, I remember learning the shell and disk methods for integrating a solid of revolution. None of this explicitly requires double integrals. (I will be ignoring improperness.) Let's see what we can get here without using the word "double integral".
Let's consider the solid $\{(x,y,z) : 0 \leq z \leq e^{-x^2+y^2}\}$.
Shell Method: The cylindrical shells of radius $r$ have height $e^{-r^2}$ and width $dr$. Its total volume is $2\pi re^{-r^2}dr$. So we integrate $$V = \int_0^\infty 2\pi re^{-r^2}dr = \pi \left(-e^{-r^2}\right)\Big\vert_0^\infty = \pi (0 - (-1)) = \pi$$
Disk Method: We cut into disks at height $z$ for $0 \leq z \leq 1$. This is the integral you discussed above. I don't want to
Special Method (Double Integrals in Disguise): We look at the disk method and say "why not cut along another plane"? The slice along $y = a$ looks like $\{(x,z) : 0 \leq z \leq e^{-a^2} e^{-x^2}$. It is the area defined by the Gaussian integral $G$, but vertically squished by a factor of $e^{-a^2}$! (We can invoke linearity here to be formal.) Now the total volume is integrating all of these slices. So it's $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a^2}G da = G\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a^2} da\right) = G^2$.
So $G^2 = \pi$! Don't you love how the exponential function factors so beautifully?
I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but it's the only resolution to your question I could see with only ideas that I think a Calc II student would be comfortable with.

I think it does work, to disguise the double integrals :)
